# regex replace repeating patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

How to use regex to replace this string below

```
var str="(adj., adv., part.) with or caution. (n.) difficult be etc., And. extreme care.";

str = str.replace(/(\w+\.)/, "*$1*");
```

to

```
(*adj.*, *adv.*, *part.*) with or caution. (*n.*) difficult be etc., And. extreme care.
```

> **\w+.** is always in **()**, and may be seperated by a **comma and space** when there are more than one.

Comment: Ok, wait... I see the source string, but what are you trying to achieve? What should the result look like?

Comment: So ah, what didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the strings that have the format you need to match and then pass the match to a callback to wrap the `\w+\.` parts with asterisks:

```
str = str.replace(/\(\w+\.(?:\s*,\s*\w+\.)*\)/g, function (m) { 
   return m.replace(/\w+\./g, "*$&*"); 
});
```

JS demo:

```js
var str="(adj., adv., part.) with or caution. (n.) difficult be etc., And. extreme care.";
console.log(str.replace(/\(\w+\.(?:\s*,\s*\w+\.)*\)/g, function (m) { 
  return m.replace(/\w+\./g, "*$&*"); 
}));
```

The regex is

```
/\(\w+\.(?:\s*,\s*\w+\.)*\)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cc7QJG/2/). Note the `g` modifier, it makes the engine search for all matches in a string.

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\w+\.` - 1+ word chars and a dot after
- `(?:\s*,\s*\w+\.)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\s*,\s*` - a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `\w+\.` - 1+ word chars and a dot after
- `\)` - a `)` char.